# AG Grid React - How to render a cell only once?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Very new to React/AG-Grid/web-dev in general. In fact, this is not my primary line of work and I am tasked with updating an existing web app, so please be gentle :)

I have an AG Grid table with two columns with the same custom renderer (a React component). This renderer takes an input, makes a network call to lookup some info for that input, and returns that info, which is what needs to get rendered in the columns. The columns have the same type of info (different values, of course), hence the use of same renderer for both.

It works well, but I want to minimize network calls and rendering latency. So I have two questions:

- How can I tell the column renderer React component to "cache" what it got for a specific input, so that if same input comes in again, it can avoid the network call? Note that this caching needs to happen outside the scope of the renderer itself, since there are two columns (two instances of the component) who should both use the cache.
- How can I tell AG Grid to not even call the renderer at all for rows that have already come into view by scrolling up/down? Right now its calling the renderer even on cells that are currently in the view (if I scroll down a millimeter, for example). Let alone calling it on cells which were in view, then got out of view coz of scrolling down, and then came back in view coz of scrolling up (even that would be an improvement over current situation).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No one has anything to say? :'(

Comment: Did you manage to solve it? I'm on the same boat.